# Electron main process modules access to app

Tags: webpack, electron, babeljs

So I need some work done in my main process. And I made some external class for it. In main process js I have:

```
import ApiClass from './api/apiclass'

global.api = new ApiClass()
```

One of api methods need to save data in path. But apiclass seems to be unable to resolve app of main process. For example:

```
import {app} from 'electron'
const path = app.getPath('home')
```

Gives me:

Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined

Importing remote in ApiClass also gives me undefined. I understand that remote is the only way to access main process from renderer. And it seems to be undefined in main process. But how can I access app from submodule? 
I don't want to path electron methods result to ApiClass conctructor, because if api changes I should change main js as well.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Are you using ApiClass in both main and renderer? What is your webpack configuration? Does this issue happen without webpack?

Comment: ApiClass only in main. However I found that import {app} from 'electron' works, but only inside class. If I try to set const on the top of module, the app will be undefined. But inside class constructor it works ok. Webpack config is from vue-electron.